# I think my Kali is broken. "sh: 1: debtags: not found" and can't upgrade

Tags: kali-linux, upgrade, software-updates

After i do apt autoremove i get this error(i think my dpkg is broken and my apt [?]):

new python3-sqlalchemy package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exi
t status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-sqlalchemy.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
installed python3-sqlalchemy package post-installation script subprocess return
ed error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-DrPwsk/00-cython3_0.29.21-1_amd64.deb
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-DrPwsk/01-python3-asn1crypto_1.3.0-1_all.deb
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-DrPwsk/02-python3-atomicwrites_1.4.0-1_all.deb
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-DrPwsk/03-python3-brotli_1.0.7-7_amd64.deb
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-DrPwsk/04-python3-capstone_4.0.1+really+3.0.5-2_amd64.deb
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-DrPwsk/05-python3-ldapdomaindump_0.9.3-1_all.deb
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-DrPwsk/06-python3-packaging_20.4-1_all.deb
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-DrPwsk/07-python3-paste_3.4.2+dfsg1-1_all.deb
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-DrPwsk/08-python3-protobuf_3.12.3-2_amd64.deb
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-DrPwsk/09-python3-py_1.8.1-4_all.deb
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-DrPwsk/10-python3-pyasn1_0.4.8-1_all.deb
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-DrPwsk/11-python3-speaklater_1.3-5_all.deb
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-DrPwsk/12-python3-sqlalchemy_1.3.18+ds1-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: did you do what the message suggests to do?

Comment: @jsotola yes i tried, this is the last line couple last lines after doing so:

Comment: @jsotola 
https://photos.app.goo.gl/sBA9sj3cxKPkvcyR6

Comment: nobody is going to look at photo of text ... there is no way to copy the text and do web searches ... if you have additional info, then use the edit button to add the text to your post ... not picture, text ... format the text same way as your previous printout

Comment: @jsotola done, this is the new output i get.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I had the same error and fixed it a moment ago. First I did

```
apt autoremove
```

then I went here https://packages.debian.org/sid/docutils-common and downloaded the file.

Did a

```
dpkg -i
```

to install the deb file.

Then I used

```
apt install --fix-broken
```

Again this fixed my install hope it helps.

Comment: I tried the apt autoremove and i get the new output above, i couldn't put the whole thing so u just copied the bottom part with hints (ig)